# Access SQL SELECT Query: Required to use the table alias in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Current Environment: Split Access Database, Local Access Front End, Access Backend on shared network drive

I'm writing a stupid long SELECT statement. Using table aliases to makes my code more readable.

I was taught to write out full table names in WHERE statements because they are executed before the FROM statement. However, when I did that - Access isn't finding the table / field referenced when I write the full table name out. Strangely, I tried using the alias in the WHERE statement and it works!!?

Does Access execute the statement differently than I was taught? Or am I unknowingly causing it to do it this way?

Shortened version of my SQL code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT [C].Multi_File_Case_ID,
[C].Case_Report_Number,
[C].Include_In_Casebook,
[C].Case_Status,
FROM Case_Tbl AS [C] 
WHERE [Case_Tbl].Include_In_Casebook = True;
```

Edit: A word and a capitalization ;)

Comment: Actually makes some sense.

Comment: `[Case_Tbl].Include_In_Casebook = True;` should be `[C].Include_In_Casebook = True;`

Comment: I was tought different, once you assign an alias to a table you have to use the alias

Comment: In most engines' SQL order of operations: `FROM` (with any `JOIN`) is usually the first clause processed. `WHERE` would then follow.

Comment: @Parfait to clarify are you saying that FROM+JOIN = executed first? And therefore FROM w/o the JOIN not executed first or am I just imagining the don't use an alias in the WHERE clause rule?

Comment: `FROM` is always first, then `JOIN` and `WHERE`. In fact, `WHERE` is considered an implicit join as it was how tables were joined prior to ANSI-92 that made explicit joins the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Once you define a table reference as an alias in the `FROM`, you need to use that alias everywhere in the query.  The alias is more than a nickname; it is a name change for the scope of the query.

I would advise you to drop the square braces.  Queries are easier to read and write as:

```
SELECT c.Multi_File_Case_ID, c.Case_Report_Number, c.Include_In_Casebook, c.Case_Status
FROM Case_Tbl AS c
WHERE c.Include_In_Casebook = True;
```

When you do not define a table alias, the table name itself serves as the alias.

Comment: More square brackets! SELECT c.[field] FROM [Case_Tbl] c (because you can proactively make your nickname not a keyword)

Comment: Square brackets are a habit I don't know I can break haha. When I took over my current ms-access project - the previous guy named all of the tables with spaces in them.

Comment: @VeryBasicApplication . . . If the previous  guy smoked cigarettes, you shouldn't start now.